# How to extrude a single polygon shape to a interpolated surface elevation in arcscene?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I have a new problem to solve which is: how to extrude a single polygon shape to the curvature of a defined surface but not only to a specific one value height? I have several interpolated surfaces and I want to extrude a rectangular polygon shape inclined to those surfaces so that I can make a block diagram of several geological layers.:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the layer properties, you can set the base height of your polygon layer based on your interpolated surface (Properties > Elevation > Floating on a custom surface). Copy-paste your layer in your data frame as many times as you need and change this property for each of your surface.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I Need a little more Suggestion;-). How can I add depth to this leyer to base layer. Thanks a lot:-)

Comment: I am afraid that you will need to create one raster layer for each depth (using raster calculator), because layer offset is not enabled for 2D features draped on a surface. A possible workaround is to use an extrusion, but this will create some volumes.

Comment: Thanks a lot @radouxju. Your suggestion perfectly worked for me.:-)